# kendo-ui angular 6 How to line up / copy widths between multiple grids?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a project that is using kendo Grids to display similar information across multiple 'sections'. The issue I'm facing is that the widths do not line up and are not the same across grids even when set correctly with similar information.

```
<!-- Section header 1 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

<!-- Section header 2 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something2" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Is there a way to 'copy' widths from one grid to another so they all line up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering with widths and percentage values, it seems that Kendo prefers pixel widths which can be ignored unless one column is left without a fixed limit so it can expand to meet the available space. This is not the best solution as it fixes columns to a specific width but at least they line up correctly.

```
<!-- Section header 1 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column width="200" field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column width="200" field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

<!-- Section header 2 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something2" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column width="200" field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column width="200" field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```